# React ScrollToTop component problem : it should work but it doesn't

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am coding a React app and I'm trying to use a ScrollToTop component in order to scroll down in the app. But the problem is that for some reason it is not working at all.

Please help I'm really struggling with this one...

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "auto" });
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

And I import this component in App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


// core styles
import "./scss/volt.scss";

// vendor styles
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css";

import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";


import ScrollToTop from "./ScrollToTop";

function App() {
    return (
    <HashRouter>
        <ScrollToTop/>
        <HomePage />
    </HashRouter>
    )
}


export default App
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: And then `window.scrollTo(0,0);` This will work for you. I edited the post
If it is not working yet, please let me know

Comment: Not even that. Maybe there is a bug in my code, because it worked first, then adding new code it stopped ..
is it possible?

Comment: Can you share the console result of browser with me? Maybe there will be the key to solve this issue.

Comment: It actually does not show any error... I'm really confused

Comment: No worry. If you can share the code, I can help you.

Comment: I solved it!!!!!!!!! there was a css 'overflow: hidden' property that caused the problem. I'm so happy, thank you for your great help and time!!